# HTML list and calculate total price

Tags: javascript, html

This may seem very simple for most programmers but as I am at the first step of programming I need a little help with this one.

What I want to do is have the user type in something in the textfield (there are only a few things they can type and they will be informed above this), and when they click the button, a list will be created with all the stuff they added. I already figured that out a bit. But I also want that a price is calculated when the user types some input.

This is what I have so far :

```
<h2> Bereken zelf de prijs van andere werken:</h2>
<p> Welke werken had u gewenst? </p>
<input align="left" type="text" name="werken" id="naamwerken">
<input type="button" value="Voeg toe" onClick="voegWerkToe()">
<ul id="werken"> </ul>
<p>Prijs excl. BTW: <span id="werkenNoBTW"> </span> </p>
<p>BTW: <span id="werkenBTW"> </span> </p>
<p>Prijs incl. BTW: <span id="werkenTotaal"> </span> </p>
```

This is my JavaScript that comes with it :

```
var werk;
var prijs = 0;
var prijsexcl = 0;
var btw = 0;


function voegWerkToe() {
var node = document.createElement("LI");
var textnode = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("naamwerken").value);
node.appendChild(textnode);
document.getElementById("werken").appendChild(node);

// werk toevoegen en prijs berekenen
var werk = document.getElementById("naamwerken").value;
if(werk == "olie vervangen")
{
    prijsexcl = 25;
}

    // berekenen van alle prijzen
    btw = (prijsexcl/100)*6;
    prijs = prijsexcl + btw;
}

// Alle prijzen in de tekst laten weergeven met 2 puntjes na de komma
document.getElementById("werkenTotaal").innerHTML = prijs.toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("werkenBTW").innerHTML = btw.toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("werkenNoBTW").innerHTML = prijsexcl.toFixed(2);
```

What would also come in handy is that next to all the items in the list the price comes up next to it?

For example these 5 things can the user type

- change oil
- change tires
- change lamp
- check before trip
- check tires

If a user types something that is not in this list an error will occur.
(But thats something I can do myself)

Kind regards!

Comment: So what is your question? What doesn't work?

Comment: Why not use a select instead? Then run your calculate function (I'm guessing it's `voegWerkToe()`, I can't really read your code) on change.

Comment: Would it not make more sense for the available items to be in a select box? You could use a plugin like [chosen.js](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) to make the options searchable and automatically select the matching option as the user types. Then onChange you'd call your function to present the price (which itself could be stored as a data-attribute within the option)

Comment: I already have code so it works with a selectable box, now I want to figure it out so the things the user type's, will be added to the list and the price has to be calculated with all things the user enters.

Comment: The price doesnt seem to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only setting the `innerHTML` of the prices elements once. You need to set these values every time `voegWerkToe()` is called.

Simply wrap those set-innerHTML lines in a function which you can call when the page loads and whenever `voegWerkToe()` is run.

```
var werk;
var prijs = 0;
var prijsexcl = 0;
var btw = 0;

function voegWerkToe() {
    var node = document.createElement("LI");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("naamwerken").value);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("werken").appendChild(node);

    // werk toevoegen en prijs berekenen
    var werk = document.getElementById("naamwerken").value;
    if(werk.toLowerCase() == "olie vervangen")// < toLowerCase() 
    {
        prijsexcl = 25;
    }

    // berekenen van alle prijzen
    btw = (prijsexcl/100)*6;
    prijs = prijsexcl + btw;

    // call the function which sets the innerHTML:
    setPrices();

}

// Create a function to set the price text:
function setPrices(){
    // Alle prijzen in de tekst laten weergeven met 2 puntjes na de komma
    document.getElementById("werkenTotaal").innerHTML = prijs.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("werkenBTW").innerHTML = btw.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("werkenNoBTW").innerHTML = prijsexcl.toFixed(2);
};

// call the function to set their initial values:
setPrices();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hwzhoxnq/

Comment: awesome! this works now, 1 quick question. How do I set what the user types to lowercase? So that it always works even if the user types something with an uppercase?